# Align figures in apa document

Tags: pgfplots, apa7

I tried to use `pgfplots` in `apa7` document which leads to some problems. How can I format figures `tikzpicture` as if it is imported with `\fitfigures`?

Here's the code

```
\documentclass{apa7}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                xlabel = $x$,
                ylabel = $f\left(x\right)$,
            ]
            \addplot{x^2}node[right]{$x^2$};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Chart 1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \fitfigures{figure/chart}
    \caption{Chart 2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This will place the figure in small size at the left side of the page, not fits the width of the page (or however `\fitfigures` would align them).

One way I can think of is to externalize the figure but it will create a small figure somewhere in the file.
Is there any solution without compiling separate files?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please make your code snippet be compilable?  Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll then select the related parts, which are proved to show the same problem.